# Selects en IONIC

Tags: ionic, select

Estoy tratando de quitar las opciones inferiores para que una vez elegida la opcion del select ya haga la funcion de OK. Sin tener que dar dos pasos para la seleccion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Pet</ion-label>
      <ion-select value="dog">
        <ion-select-option value="cat">Cat</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="dog">Dog</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

He añadido la interfaz "action-sheet" y replica bastante lo que estoy tratando de hacer. Pero cambia la manera en la que hace display del menu select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Notifications</ion-label>
      <ion-select value="notifications" interface="action-sheet">
        <ion-select-option value="enable">Enable</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="mute">Mute</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="mute_week">Mute for a week</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="mute_year">Mute for a year</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

¿Hay posibilidad de replicar el funcionamiento que comento usando el primer tipo de interfaz?

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es que en lugar de usar ion-selects uses selects normales, yo lo hago porque en muchos casos el aspecto impuesto del ion-select no me gusta, como te pasa a ti en este caso.
Puedes usar un select normal, con la directiva [(ngModel)] para referenciar la variable:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="color">
    <option value="red">Rojo</option>
</select>
```

En este caso el aspecto debería ser el mismo que tienes cuando visitas una web con el navegador.